# Create empty table with apache PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is it possible to create an empty table in Apache Pig?

Given table name, column names and column type, it is easy to do the same operation in Apache Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(name string, id int)
STORED AS ORC;
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by _"table"_ >> a Hive table, that Pig can access via its Hive Metastore integraton? Or something resembling conceptually a table-with-schema but local to your Pig job, which does not exist _(use Spark instead! )_

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create an **empty folder** within your project and use that in conjunction with your PigStorage loader.

For example:

Reading the data using PigStorage from a workflow variable `data`:

`rel = LOAD '$data' USING PigStorage('\t');`

When `data` is pointing to a file with data you'll get a non empty relation. But if you point to an empty folder (really empty, no schema too) you'll find that no code breaks and you'll eventually get an empty relation with the same schema as a non empty one.

Meaning you can run `FOREACH`, `FILTER`, `JOIN` etc.. without breaking your Pig code, all of these will be vacuously true.

Answer (score 1):

No.There is no table concept in PIG.The closest to a table is a [Relation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Relations%2C+Bags%2C+Tuples%2C+Fields).

"*A Pig relation is similar to a table in a relational database, where the tuples in the bag correspond to the rows in a table. Unlike a relational table, however, Pig relations don't require that every tuple contain the same number of fields or that the fields in the same position (column) have the same type.*"